# Avoiding SQL injections with complex dynamic SQL targeting OLEDB Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, oledb, sql-injection, linked-server, osisoft

In SQL Server 2016, I'm running a complex dynamic SQL query on an OLE-DB Linked Server, inside a stored procedure.

I'm currently building the dynamic SQL as a string, concatenating parameters in many places. So, I'm concerned about SQL injection.

The linked server is actually connecting to the OLE-DB provider interface to OSISoft PI, which is a specialised historian database. I can't define stored procedures within PI, so I think dynamic SQL is the only way to get the flexibility I need.

I do use the `QUOTENAME(input, '''')` function to wrap the user-supplied parameters in quote marks, which should also escape any quote marks found in the input. But I'm not certain if this constitutes an EFFECTIVE defense against SQL injections. I mostly did it because it makes the literals simpler in the string concatenation.

The stored procedure currently looks something like this:

```
-- Wrap user-supplied parameters in quotes to simplify SQL string building
DECLARE @Tag1   NVARCHAR(30) = QUOTENAME(@Tag1Input, '''')
DECLARE @Tag2   NVARCHAR(30) = QUOTENAME(@Tag2Input, '''')
DECLARE @Tag3   NVARCHAR(30) = QUOTENAME(@Tag3Input, '''')
DECLARE @Tag4   NVARCHAR(30) = QUOTENAME(@Tag4Input, '''')
DECLARE @Tag5   NVARCHAR(30) = QUOTENAME(@Tag5Input, '''')
DECLARE @Tag6   NVARCHAR(30) = QUOTENAME(@Tag6Input, '''')
DECLARE @Tag7   NVARCHAR(30) = QUOTENAME(@Tag7Input, '''')
DECLARE @Tag8   NVARCHAR(30) = QUOTENAME(@Tag8Input, '''')
DECLARE @Tag9   NVARCHAR(30) = QUOTENAME(@Tag9Input, '''')
DECLARE @Tag10  NVARCHAR(30) = QUOTENAME(@Tag10Input, '''')
DECLARE @starttimeq NVARCHAR(10) = QUOTENAME(@starttime, '''')
DECLARE @endtimeq   NVARCHAR(10) = QUOTENAME(@endtime, '''')
DECLARE @timestepq  NVARCHAR(10) = QUOTENAME(@timestep, '''')
DECLARE @calcbasisq NVARCHAR(30) = QUOTENAME(@calcbasis, '''')

-- Build SQL statement
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(2000) = 'SELECT tag, time, value 
FROM piarchive..piavg 
WHERE 
    tag IN (' + @Tag1 + ', ' + @Tag2 + ', ' +@Tag3 + ', ' + @Tag4 + ', ' + @Tag5 + ', ' + @Tag6 + ', ' + @Tag7+ ', ' + @Tag8 + ', ' + @Tag9 + ', ' + @Tag10 + ') 
    AND time BETWEEN ' + @starttimeq + ' AND ' + @endtimeq + '
    AND timestep = ' + @timestepq + ' 
    AND calcbasis = ' + @calcbasisq + '
UNION
SELECT ''calculatedValue'' AS tag, time, value 
FROM piarchive..piavg
WHERE 
    expr = ''(''' + @Tag2 + ''' * (''' + @Tag3 + '''-''' + @Tag4 + ''') / (''' + @Tag2 + '''-''' + @Tag4 + ''') * 100.0 + ''' + @Tag5 + ''' * (''' + @Tag4 + '''-''' + @Tag1 + ''') / (''' + @Tag5 + '''-''' + @Tag1 + ''') * (''' +@Tag3 + '''-''' + @Tag2 + ''') / (''' + @Tag4 + '''-''' + @Tag2 + ''') * 100.0) / ((''' +@Tag3 + '''-''' + @Tag4 + ''') / (''' + @Tag2 + '''-''' + @Tag4 + ''') * 100.0 + (''' + @Tag4 + '''-''' + @Tag1 + ''') / (''' + @Tag5 + '''-''' + @Tag1 + ''') * (''' +@Tag3 + '''-''' + @Tag2 + ''') / (''' + @Tag4 + '''-''' + @Tag2 + ''') * 100.0)''
    AND time BETWEEN ' + @starttimeq + ' AND ' + @endtimeq + ' 
    AND timestep = ' + @timestepq + ' 
    AND calcbasis = ' + @calcbasisq + '
ORDER BY time ASC, tag ASC'

-- Invoke dynamic SQL on PI OLEDB linked server
EXEC (@sql) AT PI
```

As far as I can tell, I can't use sp_executesql to run a query on an OLE-DB Linked Server. (Please correct me if I'm wrong).

And it seems like the `EXEC(@sql, <params>) AT LinkedServer` syntax only supports positional `?` parameters due to OLE-DB limitations. Because of the hideous `expr` filter clause, I really want to use named parameters instead of positional parameters.

How can I safely prepare this SQL string, to guard against SQL injection attacks, when I can't use sp_executesql or named parameters? Is there an elegant approach or do I just have to brute-force it with 46 positional parameters including many repeats?

Comment: Note: sp_executesql accepts parameters, allowing parameterised dynamic SQL. So e.g. you'd change `AND time BETWEEN ' + @starttimeq + ' AND ' + @endtimeq + '` to `AND time BETWEEN @starttimeq AND @endtimeq` and add @starttimeq and @endtimeq as parameters when using sp_executesql.

Comment: Ok, but how do I use sp_executesql when I need to run the query on an OLE-DB linked server rather than local tables?

Comment: Do you mean the query needs to execute on the linked server or the query runs on your sever but connects to a linked server? Because there's no reason you couldnt run sp_executesql with a query like `select 1 from mylinkedserver.database.schema.table;` unless there's an issue actually running a query on the linked server to begin with.

Comment: The SQL text needs to be passed to the linked server and executed there (e.g. by using `EXEC(@sql) AT PI` or `OPENQUERY(PI, sql)`) rather than executed within the SQL Server context. This is because OSISoft PI has a different way of interpreting times that isn't supported by SQL Server, and I'm expecting to receive start and end time parameters in that format.

PI supports syntax like `time BETWEEN 't-8h' AND '*'` which isn't valid as an SQL Server T-SQL statement.

Comment: Could you not do something like `exec mylinkedserver.database.schema.sp_executesql @sql...`? This would make sp_executesql run in the context of the linked server.

Comment: The linked server isn't an SQL Server. It's an OLE-DB provider to a completely different database system (OSISoft PI). It doesn't contain sp_executesql.

Comment: Unless there's some alternative to it on that server, then I don't know of any way you could use named parameters with dynamic sql.

Comment: In the absence of named parameter support, is there another safe way to sanitise the inputs to prevent SQL injection?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, outside of your idea about EXEC with 40+ question marks (though I'm not sure that actually sanitises the input since I haven't personally tested it, I would guess it does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I worked with the administrators of the PI system to enable the PI DATE and TIME function views within the pifunction catalog. These function views convert the PI-specific time literals into formats that SQL Server can handle, within the SQL Server execution context. (When I tried to set up these function views myself I got an error dialog which said `Error creating TIME - View creation failed. [PI SDK] Item not found in collection: %OSI`. It turns out this error was caused by my account not having sufficient security permissions within PI.)

After the function views were set up, I could replace the dynamic SQL with a conventional SQL query running inside the SQL Server context, using standard parameter substitutions. This eliminates the SQL injection risk, as well as significantly improving the readability of the code.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to return with a solution